# Fixed point power function

Tags: c++, c, signal-processing, fixed-point

I have question regarding how to handle some fixed point calculations. I can't figure out how to solve it. I know it is easy in floating point, but i want to figure out how to do it in fixed point.

I have a fixed point system where i am performing the following equation on a signal (vSignal):

```
Signal_amplified = vSignal * 10^Exp
```

The vSignal has an max amplitude of around 4e+05,

The system allows for representation of 2.1475e+09 (32 bit) signals. So there is some headroom for Signal_amplified.

For simplicity reason, lest just assume Exp can go from 0 to 10.

Lets say the first value is 2.8928. This value works well when calculating in floating point, since the expresson 10^2.8928 results in 781. When using a rounded floating point value 781 i get signal amplitudes of 3.0085e+08, well within the signal range.

If i try to represent the value 2.8928 with a Q format of, lets say Q12. The value changes to 11849. Now 10^11849 results in overflow.

How should one handle these large numbers?? I Could use another formatting like Q4, but even then the numbers get very large and my becomes poor. I would very much like to be able to calculate with a precision of .001, but i just can see how this should be done.

Minimal Working Example:

```
int vSignal = 400000

// Floatingpoint -> Goes well
double dExp = 2.89285
double dSignal_amplified = vSignal * std::pow(10,dExp)

// Fixedpoint -> Overflow
int iExp = 11848 // Q12 format
int iSignal_amplified = vSignal * std::pow(10,iExp)
iSignal_amplified =  iSignal_amplified>>12
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused about what language you are using.  You've tagged _both_ C and C++, and then provided an example in Python.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I simulated in Python, but I am implementing in C/C++. But the same problem holds in both language. It was just to provide an example.

Comment: By what method is `10^Exp` computed in fixed point? Shouldn't this calculation take into account the fixed point unit? It's not like 10^(2^(-k)) has any nice representation that would allow you to directly transfer binary places from input to output (did you plan to divide by `10^(2(-k))` afterwards?), so how would all of this work in the first place?

Comment: Your fixed point example code is wrong even without overflow (that answers my above questions I guess). `10^(x/y)` is not the same as `(10^x) / y` (where `y = 2^k` in this case). [Note: Using `^` for exponentiation here, not `xor`.]

Comment: "The value changes to 11849". No, it doesn't. The representation changes to `0x2e49`. The value changes to ‭2.892822265625‬. You're confusing fixed-point numbers and their binary representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If i try to represent the value 2.8928 with a Q format of, lets say Q12. The value changes to 11849. Now 10^11849 results in overflow.".

Mixed-type math is pretty hard, and it looks like you should avoid it. What you want is `pow(Q12(10.0), Q12(2.8928))` or possibly an optimized `pow10(Q12(2.8928))`. For the first, see [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657468/fast-fixed-point-pow-log-exp-and-sqrt/4657849#4657849). The latter can be optimized by a hardcoded table of powers. `pow10(2.8928)` is of course `pow10(2) * pow10(.5) * pow10(.25) * pow10(.125) * ...` - each 1 in the binary representation of `2.8928` corresponds to a single table entry. You may want to calculate the intermediate results in Q19.44 and drop the lowest 32 bits when you return..

### Edit: Precision

Storing all the values of `pow10(2^-n)` up to n=12 has the slight problem that the result is close to 1, namely `1.000562312`. If you'd store that as a Q12, you lose precision in rounding. Instead, it may be wise to store the value of `pow10(2^-12)` as a Q24, the value of `pow10(2^-121)` as a Q23 etc. Now evaluate `Q12 pow10(Q12 exp)` starting at the LSB of `exp`, not the MSB. You need to repeatedly shift the intermediate results as you move up to `pow10(0.5)` but half of the time you can merge that with the `>>12` that's inherent to Q12 multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. I know one should avoid Mixed-type math, but sometimes it is a necessity when the system only accepts one type and the calculations are defined using another type. I need to focus on speed so i am going with the latter option of a hardcoded table. Thx, again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal. It's just a rough idea, that needs to be adjusted and refined.

Say you need a precision of `0.01` (you can choose the precision you need of course) you can represent the exponent as: `Exp = N + M*10^-1 + P*10^-2`where N, M and P are integers and M and P are between 0 and 9.

Then you pre-compute and round all values for `10^(M*10^-1) * 100` and `10^(P*10^-2) * 100`. They are all between 1 and 1000. Store them in a lookup table to avoid computing float operations at runtime. Let's call these lookup tables A[M] and B[P].

Then you can compute `10^Exp =( 10^N * A[M] * B[P] ) / 10000`

The multiplication should not overflow since `A[M] * B[P]` is between 1 and 1,000,000 and A is lower than 10 according to what you said.

I did a quick test with a few values and it seems to give an acceptable precision.

Comment: That rounding of pre-computed values sounds scary. If you happen to choose an `Exp` where e.g. all of them were rounded down you might get a pretty high error in the result? I'm also not sure how this scales to more digits - you quickly get into overflow again as you add more digits. I think it would be more promising to reduce the problem to binary exponentiation (then figuring out the result decimals is easier) and trying to control the error in the `ln(10)/ln(2)` exponent factor.

Comment: An example for the rounding problem: With 12 fixed digits you would have a maximum error of 0.5 * 10^-12 in each table entry, which could aggregate to about 12 x 0.5 * 10^-12 = 6 * 10^-12 relative error (i.e. the last digit of the result may be completely lost to this error). Or in general, if you have `k` digits, you will have an error of about `k` ULP with this scheme. Could be mitigated by having higher intermediate resolution, but the multiplication of the table entries would overflow even faster.

Comment: Good comments @MaxLanghof. About the precision, it's hard to say if it's acceptable. but the main problem of my proposal is that it probably overflows quickly if you increase the number of digits. I think the best solution if to look at the bigger picture: first, why can't the OP use floating point even in software ? Is there really a performance issue. If there is, how is this amplified signal used further in the software, etc...

Comment: The base-10 is weird. Computers aren't decimal. Instead, you use binary, and way more than 2 digits/bits. This may seem a bit expensive, but instead of two tables `A[10]` and `B[10]` you now only have one value per bit. So for the same amount of precalculated values, you now get 20 bits of precision = 6 digits, not 2.

Comment: As I said it was a rough idea and needs to be refined. Switching to base 2 is better, you're right.

Comment: I know the ideal case would have been to work in floating point, but the all mighty cost price & time overrules all the sane options like switching to a new DSP or altering previously defined amplification calculations etc. sometimes one just have to make the better of what he/she got. None the less, a solution was found for my implementation and that was really the issue, not the if, but the how.